# Would it make sense to package a ruby shell script as a gem?

Tags: ruby

I've written a shell script that I find very useful and would like to reuse. Basically, it reads an excel file (via the RubyXL gem) and then allows users to take certain rows and export them as json objects.  However, because it relies on passing many arguments (columns, rows, ect.), I'm wondering if packaging this as a gem would be a good use.  I haven't published a gem but I've read through and it seems like it wouldn't be that difficult.  I'm wondering how useful or if a shell script is really the right format?

Comment: i think it's better to make a github gist and pull it whenever you need the script. or make the script generic enough with easy configuration options and good documentation to bundle as a gem.

Comment: Yeah, I think the gist maybe the better approach.

Comment: You could use the GLI gem to make a command line app, and if you don't want to push to RubyGems, you can store it on GitHub, since bundler allows you to install gems from GitHub.

Comment: Very cool, hadn't seen that!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say yes to making it a gem, but only if you expose the functionality as Ruby classes and/or methods, so that your functionality could be called by other Ruby scripts, and not just the command line.

This would enable you to better organize your code; your `lib` directory would contain the core logic, a `spec` or `test` directory would have unit tests, and the `bin` directory would have your command line script, which would probably be just a tiny wrapper that called the `lib` code.

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't built it that way but I think the conversion wouldn't be too bad given the size of it.